# Обьекты, созданные через "=" и конструктор - в чем отличия?

Tags: javascript, объекты

)
Почему только у обьекта, созданного через конструктор есть контекст? Какие концептуальные разницы между объектом, созданным через =, и обьектом, созданным через конструктор?
example:

```
    function constructor(firstName, lastName) {
       // this !== window (есть собственный this)
    } 
    const obj = {
        // this === window (нет собственного this)
    }
```

Comment: Покажите примеры хоть, а то ваша терминология непонятна

Comment: дополннил вопрос)

Comment: `this` зависит о того, как вызывается функция. Во втором примере у вас нету функции. Как во втором примере вы используете `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Второе утверждение ошибочно. В объекте можно указать метод, то есть функцию, которая будет иметь this, который ссылается на родительский объект.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'local',
  method() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

obj.method();
```

К тому же, первое утверждение, тоже частично неправильное. Если мы просто запустим функцию, то this указывает на внешнее окружение, то есть на window. И только если мы используем функцию как конструктор, то можем использовать this в качестве привязки.

Документация очень хорошо с примерами все описывает. И bind, call, apply, и get/set, и многое другое.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Про второе утверджение все же замечу, что мною было явно указано про вызов функции в виде конструктора

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Я заметил. Решил уточнить, чтоб уж наверняка)))

Answer (score 0):

### дополню с примером `instanceof`

```js
function Qwa() {} 

const { log } = console

log({} instanceof Object)                   // true
log(Object.create(null) instanceof Object)  // false
log(new Qwa instanceof Object)              // true
log(new Qwa instanceof Qwa)                 // true
```

```js
const { log } = console

class Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }

log(new Cat instanceof Cat   ) // true
log(new Cat instanceof Animal) // true
log(new Cat instanceof Object) // true
```